# Error message 887c499c-ef3d-40c5-0fc9-dbcbaed12ad2

Tags: error

WHen I create a MySite host and then I recieved a error message with correlation ID: 887c499c-ef3d-40c5-0fc9-dbcbaed12ad2

I tried googling by no answer came up. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation id is unique to your request/operation to your SharePoint farm this will always be unique, so googling for it will never give anything usefull.

Read [Get the Real SharePoint Error using the ULS Logs](http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/en/insights/Get-the-Real-SharePoint-Error-using-the-ULS-Logs.aspx#.Uk9Gvcu9KSM) for how to get the real error message

Comment: Does your advice also support for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: I also tried locating the address below

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsot shared\web server extensions\14\logs" but no "logs" for SharePoint 2013 exist.

Comment: In SP2013 the default directory is `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\logs`